# Mysql Delete all matching values if another column satisfies a condition

Tags: mysql

I have the below table `order_details`:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      order_id       |    sap_number    |   product_name   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         123      |     earphones    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         123      |      battery     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         456      |      charger     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         789      |       phone      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I want to delete all those records having same sap_number if product is battery. In this case I want records with order_id 1 and 2 to be deleted.

I tried this:

```
delete from order_details 
where order_id in (
  select order_id
  from (
      select order_id
      from order_details
      group by sap_number
      having product = 'battery'
      ) t
)
```

but it deletes only the second record and not the first one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 delete from order_details where sap_number IN (select sap_number from (select * from order_details  having product_name = 'battery') t);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below

```
delete from order_details 
where sap_number in (
      select sap_number
      from order_details
      where product_name= 'battery'
      )
```